# how can I decently add an "undo" functionality to State monads?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

Say that I have a State monad, and I want to do some manipulations on the state and might want to undo the change in future. How in general can I do this decently?

To give a concrete example, let's assume the state is just an `Int`, and the manipulation
is just to increase the number by one.

```
type TestM a = StateT a IO ()

inc :: TestM Int
inc = modify (+ 1)
```

however, if I want to keep track of all the history of states in case I want to undo to some previous state, the best I can think of is to wrap the states in a stack: every modification to the state will be pushed to the stack so that I can undo changes through droping the top element on the stack.

```
-- just for showing what's going on
traceState :: (MonadIO m, MonadState s m, Show s) => m a -> m a
traceState m = get >>= liftIO . print >> m

recordDo :: TestM a -> TestM [a]
recordDo m = do
    x <- gets head
    y <- liftIO $ execStateT m x
    modify (y:)

inc' :: TestM [Int]
inc' = recordDo inc

undo' :: TestM [Int]
undo' = modify tail

-- inc 5 times, undo, and redo inc
manip' :: TestM [Int]
manip' = mapM_ traceState (replicate 5 inc' ++ [undo',inc'])

main :: IO ()
main = do
    v1 <- execStateT (replicateM_ 5 (traceState inc)) 2
    v2 <- execStateT (replicateM_ 5 (traceState inc')) [2]
    v3 <- execStateT manip' [2]
    print (v1,v2,v3)
```

As expected, here is the output:

```
2
3
4
5
6
[2]
[3,2]
[4,3,2]
[5,4,3,2]
[6,5,4,3,2]
[2]
[3,2]
[4,3,2]
[5,4,3,2]
[6,5,4,3,2]
[7,6,5,4,3,2]
[6,5,4,3,2]
(7,[7,6,5,4,3,2],[7,6,5,4,3,2])
```

The drawback of my approach:

- `tail` and `head` are unsafe
- One have to use something like `recordDo` explicitly, but I guess this is unavoidable because otherwise there will be some inconsistency issue. For example increasing the number by two can be done by either `inc' >> inc'` or `recordDo (inc >> inc)` and these two approach have different effects on the stack.

So I'm looking for either some ways to make it more decent or something that does the job of "reversible state" better.

Comment: Would check-pointing be more agreeable?  You could make a new monad `type Undoable s m a = StateT (Map Checkpoint s) (StateT s m) a` and include helper functions of `mkCheckpoint :: Undoable s m Checkpoint` and `revertToCheckpoint :: Checkpoint -> Undoable s m a`.

Comment: Have you looked at [tardis](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tardis-0.3.0.0)?

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson that looks more powerful than I want, having the ability to go back to the most recent history will be sufficent. Maybe I'll just improve my approach with `safeHead` and `safeTail`. but that looks a little more verbose though.

Comment: @bheklilr @bitemyapp has pointed me to tardis before, but I didn't quite get it and thought I don't really need a `MonadFix` to do the job. But anyway since you both think that would help me out, I guess I need to try that out myself.

Comment: A stack is what I would use too.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson That seems like overkill.  Why not just `mkCheckpoint  = get` and `revertToCheckpoint = put`?

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez that is certainly better. For asthetics I'd probably return an opaque wrapper instead of a raw `s` though.

Comment: I'd probably use a stack also, but if I wanted to try something clever I might look into the approach I outlined at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5193876/goto-in-haskell-can-anyone-explain-this-seemingly-insane-effect-of-continuation/5203603#5203603

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez Why not just `checkpoint = get >>= return . put` which you use like `do revert <- checkpoint; somethingToUndo; revert`?

Comment: @Cirdec I like your idea even better, except refactoring `checkPoint` to use `fmap` instead: `checkpoint = fmap put get`

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your use-case, it might be worth considering something that I'd call "delimited undo":

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleContexts #-}
import Control.Applicative
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.State
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe

undo :: (MonadState s m, MonadPlus m) => m a -> m a -> m a
undo dflt k = do
    s <- get
    k `mplus` (put s >> dflt)

undoMaybe :: (MonadState s m) => m a -> MaybeT m a -> m a
undoMaybe dflt k = do
    s <- get
    r <- runMaybeT k
    maybe (put s >> dflt) return r

undoMaybe_ :: (MonadState s m) => MaybeT m () -> m ()
undoMaybe_ = undoMaybe (return ())
```

Executing `undo x k` means "execute `k`, and if it fails, undo the state and execute `x` instead". Function `undoMaybe` works similarly, but allows the failure only the nested block. Your example then could be expressed as:

```
type TestM a = StateT a IO ()

inc :: (MonadState Int m) => m ()
inc = modify (+ 1)

-- just for showing what's going on
traceState :: (MonadIO m, MonadState s m, Show s) => m a -> m a
traceState m = get >>= liftIO . print >> m

inc' :: (MonadIO m, MonadState Int m) => m ()
inc' = traceState inc

-- inc 5 times, undo, and redo inc
manip' :: TestM Int
manip' = replicateM 4 inc' >> undoMaybe_ (inc' >> traceState mzero) >> inc'

main :: IO ()
main = do
    v1 <- execStateT (replicateM_ 5 (traceState inc)) 2
    putStrLn ""
    v3 <- execStateT manip' 2
    print (v1,v3)
```

The main advantage is that you can never underflow the stack. The disadvantage is that you can't access the stack and the undo is always delimited.

One could also create an `Undo` monad transformer that where the above `undo` becomes `mplus`. Whenever a failed computation is restored with `mplus`, the state is restored as well.

```
newtype Undo m a = Undo (m a)
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad)

instance MonadTrans Undo where
    lift = Undo

instance (MonadState s m) => MonadState s (Undo m) where
    get = lift get
    put = lift . put
    state = lift . state

instance (MonadPlus m, MonadState s m) => MonadPlus (Undo m) where
    mzero = lift mzero
    x `mplus` y = do
        s <- get
        x `mplus` (put s >> y)
```