# Space leaks, and Writers, and Sums (oh my!)

Tags: haskell, space-leak, writer-monad

I've been playing with the Writer Monad recently, and I've run into
what appears to be a space leak.  I can't say I fully understand these
things yet, so I'd like to know what's happening here, and how to fix it.

First, here's how I can trigger this error:

```
import Control.Monad.Writer
import Data.Monoid

foo :: Integer -> Writer (Sum Integer) Integer
foo 0 = return 0
foo x = tell (Sum x) >> foo (pred x)

main = print $ runWriter $ foo 1000000
```

I get:

```
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

To understand this better, I've reimplemented similar functionality
without Writer or Sum, and if I keep things nice and lazy, I get the
same error:

```
bar :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
bar x = bar' 0 x
    where bar' c 0 = (0, c)
          bar' c x = bar' (c + x) (pred x)
```

But I can remedy this by adding `seq` to the equation:

```
bar' c x = c `seq` bar' (c + x) (pred x)
```

I've tried `seq`ing various bits of my `foo` function, but that doesn't seem
to help.  Also, I've tried using `Control.Monad.Writer.Strict` but that
doesn't make a difference either.

Does `Sum` need to be strict somehow?  Or am I missing something
completely different?

**Notes**

- I may have my terminology wrong here.  According to [Space leak
  zoo](http://blog.ezyang.com/2011/05/space-leak-zoo/), my problem would be classified as a 'stack overflow', and if
  that's the case, how would I convert `foo` to a more iterative style?  Is my manual
  recursion the problem?
- After reading [Haskell Space Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140732/haskell-space-overflow), I had
  the idea to compile with `-O2`, just to see what happens.  This may be a topic for
  another question, but with optimizations, even my `seq`'d `bar` function fails to run.
  **Update**: This issue goes away if I add `-fno-full-laziness`.

Comment: `Sum` is a `newtype` so it's as strict or lazy as the underlying type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem with Writer monad is that it's  `>>=` is not tail-recursive:

```
instance (Monoid w, Monad m) => Monad (WriterT w m) where
m >>= k  = WriterT $ do
    (a, w)  <- runWriterT m
    (b, w') <- runWriterT (k a)
    return (b, w `mappend` w')
```

As you can see it has to evaluate both `m` and `k a` to evaluate `mappend` which means the entire stack of recursive calls has to be forced before the first `mappend` can be evaluated. I believe that regardless of the strictness Writer monad will cause stack overflow in your definition (or can it be avoided with *lazy* version somehow?).

If you still want to use monads you can try `State` which is tail-recursive. Either strict version of it with strict `put`:

```
import Control.Monad.State.Strict

foo :: Integer -> State (Sum Integer) Integer
foo 0 = return 0
foo x = do
   w <- get
   put $! w `mappend` (Sum x)
   foo (pred x)

main = print $ (`execState` Sum 0) $ foo 1000000
```

Or lazy version with continuation passing style (CPS):

```
import Control.Monad.Cont
import Control.Monad.State.Lazy

foo :: Integer -> ContT Integer (State (Sum Integer)) Integer
foo 0 = return 0
foo x = do
  w <- get
  put $! w `mappend` (Sum x)
  foo (pred x)

main = print $ ((`execState`Sum 0) . (`runContT`return)) $ foo 1000000
```

Handy analog for `tell`:

```
stell :: (MonadState w m, Monoid w) => w -> m ()
stell a = get >>= \w -> put $! w `mappend` a
```

I suspect that if it was possible to use `ContT` with `Writer` CPS would help us with `Writer` as well, but looks like it isn't possible to [define ContT for MonadWriter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5166601/impossible-to-derive-instance-of-monadwriter-for-continuation-monad-transformer):

Comment: Interesting... I guess I'll have to move `State` and `Cont` up on my list of things learn.  I understand why your `State.Strict` implementation works, but I'm not sure I understand why your `State.Lazy` and `Cont` version works.

Comment: Here, for example: http://users.aber.ac.uk/afc/stricthaskell.html#cps Also, look at `>>=` in ContT: `m >>= k  = ContT $ \c -> runContT m (\a -> runContT (k a) c)` - it doesn't even use `>>=` of the internal monad (and strict)

Answer (score 7):

Look at the source for the strict writer monad: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/transformers/0.2.2.0/doc/html/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Writer-Strict.html#line-122

The difference from the lazy writer is that in the latter, the pattern matches are lazy -- but in neither case is the `mappend` operation or the "state" of the writer thus far forced. To solve your issue, you'd need a "super-strict" writer.

Comment: So I assume, since no such Writer exists, my approach is wrong?  I don't need this for anything in particular, just testing the bounds of things for better understanding.

Comment: Is there a reason a stricter writer cannot exist? I wrote this, didn't get to try it:
https://github.com/Blaisorblade/pts/commit/29b59f0c9f869a7db83133e7f31cd9efe40ee98c#diff-f8379ae3302d3d9e41dd56fd896ef630R144

Answer (score 4):

I think your understanding is correct.

I'm interested in how these functions:

```
bar :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
bar x = bar' 0 x
    where bar' c 0 = (0, c)
          bar' c x = c `seq` bar' (c + x) (pred x)
      --  bar' c x = let c' = c+x in c' `seq` bar' c' (pred x)
      --  bar' !c !x = bar' (c+x) (pred x)
```

produces a stack overflow when compiled with optimizations, although the related functions:

```
bar2 :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
bar2 x = bar' 0 x
     where bar' c 0 = (0, c)
           bar' !c !x = let c' = c+x in c' `seq` bar' c' (pred x)

bar3 :: Integer -> Integer
bar3 x = bar' 0 x
     where bar' c 0 = c
           bar' c x = c `seq` bar' (c + x) (pred x)

bar4 :: Integer -> (Integer, Integer)
bar4 x = (0, bar' 0 x)
     where bar' c 0 = c
           bar' c x = c `seq` bar' (c + x) (pred x)
```

do not.

I think this looks like a bug in GHC's optimizer, and you should [report it](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ReportABug).  From looking at the core (produced with `-ddump-simpl`), the `c` argument isn't strictly evaluated in all cases for the overflowing functions.  `bar2` is the closest working version I found to the original, and it seems over-specified to me.

Since you have a very simple test case, there's a good chance it'll get fixed.

Comment: I've found this ticket on GHC's trac:  http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/5262.  I'm assuming this is the same bug

Comment: @AdamWagner: looks like it.  Adding `-fno-full-laziness` fixed the leak for me.