# Why no MonadWriter instance for ParsecT?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers, parsec

I was writing some Haskell earlier today. Came up with something along the lines of

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving #-}

newtype Foo a = Foo { ParsecT String () (Writer DefinitelyAMonoid) a }
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadWriter DefinitelyAMonoid)
```

This did not compile. "No instance for `(MonadWriter DefinitelyAMonoid (ParsecT String () (Writer DefinitelyAMonoid)))` arising from the 'deriving' clause of a data type declaration", GHC told me. So I decided to see if some other MTL classes would work, and they did. `Reader` and `MonadReader`, and `Writer` and `MonadWriter`. So I <del>turned</del> was directed by a Discord user to [Hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.14.0/docs/Text-Parsec.html), where the problem was clear:

```hs
MonadState  s m => MonadState  s (ParsecT s' u m)
MonadReader r m => MonadReader r (ParsecT s  u m)
MonadError  e m => MonadError  e (ParsecT s  u m)
```

No `MonadWriter` instance can make it through the `ParsecT` transformer! Seemed for all the world to me like a mere oversight, and I just barely realized before opening an issue on Github that this might be deliberate. So I took a look at [Megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec-9.0.0/docs/Text-Megaparsec.html):

```hs
(Stream s, MonadState st m) => MonadState st (ParsecT e s m)
(Stream s, MonadReader r m) => MonadReader r (ParsecT e s m)
(Stream s, MonadError e' m) => MonadError e' (ParsecT e s m)
```

Again, no `MonadWriter`.

Why do neither Parsec nor Megaparsec provide a `MonadWriter` instance for `ParsecT`? Is there something special about parser monads like these that keep them from playing nice with writers? Is there something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5171420/5499914) going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parsec is a backtracking monad.  While the `MonadWriter` instance you propose is not impossible, it's a strange thing to put a `Writer` underneath a backtracking monad.  This is because the inner layers of a monad stack provide the "foundational" effects upon which the outer layers build -- that is, whatever `ParsecT u (Writer w)` does, it must do so only *in terms of* `tell`.  So if it `tell`s a value in a branch that is later backtracked out of, there is no possibility to "untell" that value, and so the `Writer`'s result will be more like a trace of the parsing *algorithm* rather than a trace of the dataflow abstraction that Parsec is presenting.  It's not useless, but it's pretty odd, and you would have much more natural semantics if `WriterT` were on the outside and `Parsec` on the inside.

The same argument applies to `State`.  Parsec exposes both its own user state functionality (the `u` parameter) and a `MonadState` instance that inherits the underlying monad's state functionality.  The latter comes with the same caveats as `MonadWriter` -- the statefulness follows the trace of the algorithm, not the dataflow.  I don't know why this instance was included while the `Writer` instance was not; they are both tricky in the same way.

```
-- I'm presuming the user might want a separate, non-backtracking
-- state aside from the Parsec user state.
instance (MonadState s m) => MonadState s (ParsecT s' u m) where
    get = lift get
    put = lift . put
```

Parsec's user state, on the other hand, follows the dataflow, not computation, and it has the same effect as putting `StateT` on the outside.  It always seemed odd that Parsec provides its own state facility rather than just asking us to use a transformer -- but, thinking about it now, I suspect it is just to avoid having to put `lift` all over the place if you do happen to use state.

In conclusion, they could provide the `MonadWriter` instance you ask for, but I think there is a decent reason not to -- to discourage making the mistake that I think you are probably making.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. And I see why `MonadParsec` lifts through `WriterT`. Many thanks!